# AWK command not printing all line of files

Tags: awk

**script.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh


awk '{if ($1=="%%Page:" && $2=="(1)" && $3== "1" ) {print "%%BeginPageSetup""\n""<<"" ""/Duplex" ;print $0;}

else if($1=="%%Page:" && $2=="(2)" && $3== "2" )  {print "%%BeginPageSetup" ;print $0}}' $1 > ss.txt
```

**input.txt**

```
vaibhav
gupta
%%Page: (1) 1
vaibhav
gupta
%%Page: (2) 2
vaibhav
```

Running:

```
./script.sh input.text
```

**Output:**

```
%%BeginPageSetup
<< /Duplex
%%Page: (1) 1
%%BeginPageSetup
%%Page: (2) 2
```

output should be

```
vaibhav
gupta
%%BeginPageSetup
<< /Duplex
%%Page: (1) 1
vaibhav
gupta
%%BeginPageSetup
vaibhav
```

something like above.

Comment: Format your code first please.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

It prints what you aks it to print:

```
if ($1=="%%Page:" && $2=="(1)" && $3== "1" ) ...
else if($1=="%%Page:" && $2=="(2)" && $3== "2" ) ...
```

"if first field is `%%Page:` and second and third fields are `(1)` and `1` or `(2)` and `2`".

Looks like this crap:

```
ffjfjfjfjfjdrrr
gghhhhhh

dhjdfhjfhjfdhj
errrrrrrrre

ryryryryryryry
```

classifies to none of your coded requirements.

To get your expected output, before: `}' $1 > ss.txt` add something like: `else print`.

Comment: i need below output, please suggest how to get it 

ffjfjfjfjfjdrrr
gghhhhhh
"%%BeginPageSetup""\n""<<"" ""/Duplex"" ""false"" ""/MediaType"" ""(Main)"" "">>"" ""setpagedevice""\n""%%EndPageSetup""\n"
%%Page: (1) 1
dhjdfhjfhjfdhj
errrrrrrrre
"%%BeginPageSetup"
%%Page: (2) 2
ryryryryryryry

Comment: Please put that extra requirement to the original post, it really is uncomprehensible in the comment field since it lacks all newlines.

Comment: sorry for inconvenience : site is restricting me to post a new question
i just want below lines also in output file apart from what i print after meeting the condition

ffjfjfjfjfjdrrr
gghhhhhh

dhjdfhjfhjfdhj
errrrrrrrre

ryryryryryryry

Comment: Don't post a new question. Edit your original post. Just below and to the left of your original post there are: **share edit close flag**. Click on **edit**, paste your requirement in there, paint it with your mouse and hit **{}**.

Comment: Did you take a look at it? Paint the pieces of code and, inputs and outputs etc. with your mouse (each excerpt individually) and click **{}**. Learn to do it properly now and you will get proper answer more easily, faster and everybody saves time.